# Change color of stripes

Tags: css, background-color

I have a striped black diamond using the class `diamond` (see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UQQMz/)):

```
.diamond {
    border: 8px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 12%;
    width: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5) rotate(45deg);
}
.diamond:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -37.5%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -37.5%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(black 50%, transparent 50%);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.155) skewX(-30deg) rotate(30deg);
    background-size: 10px;
    content: '';
}
```

Now I want a class `red` that will make the diamond red, both the border and the stripes. I have managed to impose a red border, but not the red stripes. How can I modify the CSS for `.red` such that the stripes become red?

Comment: FWIW I don't see stripes in either fiddle posted to date in FF. Just black and a red squares.

Comment: My code is WebKit only for now. Sorry.

Comment: Gah. I should've seen that. Thanks.

Comment: "Works only in WebKit" is the new "Works only in IE6" http://www.glazman.org/weblog/dotclear/index.php?post/2012/02/09/CALL-FOR-ACTION:-THE-OPEN-WEB-NEEDS-YOU-NOW  ... please, *please,* start with the standards and add vendor prefixes only when necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.diamond {
    border: 8px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 12%;
    width: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5) rotate(45deg);
}
.diamond:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -37.5%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -37.5%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(black 50%, transparent 50%);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.155) skewX(-30deg) rotate(30deg);
    background-size: 10px;
    content: '';
}
.red {
    border-color: crimson !important;
}
.red:before {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(red 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UQQMz/1/

Comment: Hold on. Why did you use `background-image`? An explanation would be nice.

Comment: Because if you use just `background` it will overwrite `background-size: 10px`.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is the order of precedence. The `red` class is handled before the `diamond` class because it appears in the CSS first. Move the `red` classes below the `diamond` class to fix your problem.

Comment: Try it and see - with the `red` classes above, the stripes remain black, but with the `red` classes below, the `red:before` class comes into play.